# An issue with type-asserting and type-converstion

Tags: go

I have the following situation.

```
type A func(x int) int
type B func(x int) A

var testFunc = func() B {
    var ret interface{} = func(x int) A {
        return func(y int) int {
            return x * y
        }
    }
    return ret.(func(x int) A)
    //return ret.(B)
}

func main() {
    var res = testFunc()(1)(2)
    fmt.Println("Here the result", res)
}
```

Looking at the snippet above, this is what I am trying to do.

First I define a `type A` which is a function which takes an `int` and returns an `int`.

Then I define a `type B` which is a function that takes an `int` and returns an `A`, i.e. `B` is an higher level function returning an `A`.

Then I define a `testFunc`, which is a function which returns a `B`, as defined in its signature.

Now, let's look at the body of `testFunc`. In here I define a `ret` variable as `interface{}` and then I set its value to a function that takes an `int` and returns an `A`, which is what `B` is. So, within `testFunc`, I end up doing the following operations:

1. I type-seert `ret`, which is a variable of type `interface{}`, against the type `func(x int) A`
2. Then, while returning `ret`, what I sense is that, given the signature of `testFunc` which specifies `B` as return type, there is an implicit type-conversion from `func(x int) A` to `B`

My problem is the following. If, in `testFunc`, I type-assert the `ret` variable against `func(x int) A`, everything works as charm.

But if I type-assert the `ret` variable against `B`, which is what you see in the commented line at the end of `testFunc`, I get the error

```
panic: interface conversion: interface {} is func(int) main.A, not main.B
```

Why the somehow implicit conversion from `func(int) main.A` to `B` works while the explicit type-assertion does not?

Here is a ["playground" reproducing the case](https://play.golang.org/p/jkSYKAjgr5f).

**RESPONSE AFTER HAVING READ THE CONTRIBUTION GIVEN IN THE ANSWERS AND COMMENTS**

`B` is based on `func(int) main.A` as its source type but it is a **different type**. Therefore the type assertion of `ret` against type `func(int) main.A` actually works, but the type-assertion against `B` generates an error.

When returning, the function `testFunc` performs a type-convertion, i.e. copies `ret` to a new value of type `B` implicitly performing the `B(ret)` operation.

If I had used type aliases, i.e. if I had defined `B` as an alias of `func(int) main.A` like this

```
type B = func(int) main.A
```

type assertion `ret.(B)` would have worked since in this case `B` is just another name, i.e. an alias, of `func(int) main.A`.

Comment: Note that Go doesn't allow typecasting at all. What you're doing are type conversions.

Comment: You are right. I have corrected the text and added an answer specifically tailored for my case.

Answer (score 1):

You are not type-casting, you using type-assertion. Type assertion tests if the underlying type of an interface is the requested type.

```
var ret interface{} = func(x int) A {...}
```

Above, `ret` is an interface containing a `func(x int) A`, and it is not `B`. You can copy the function to a `B`, and then the type-assertion works:

```
var ret interface{} = B(func(x int) A {...})
// Here, ret is of type B
return ret.(B)
```

Comment: You are right. I have corrected the text of the question based on your observations and added an answer specifically tailored for my case.